# Mirror effect of an image, why need to do bitwise reversal?

Tags: algorithm

When you try to "mirror" an image, left-to-right style, you could just swap the pixels like this:

```
for i:= 0 to width / 2
  for j:= 0 to height
    swap pixel[i][j] with pixel[width-i][j]
```

But why do we need to do bitwise on each 8bit pixel(stored as char in C) ?

Comment: What do you mean by _bitwise_?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do a bitwise reversal on the individual pixels; where do you read that you are supposed to?

Comment: @templatetypedef possibly for a pixmap? One black/white pixel per bit

Comment: @MartinBeckett yes, 8 bit pixmap

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a pixel is not actually a pixel and represents more than one visible point in the screen, you need to reverse the bits because you want to read them left to right so that the image is completely reversed. Otherwise, you would have each smaller structure being shown "right to left" and the whole figure being shon "left to right", having a result that is not a full reversal.